# How to remove a VS command line switch

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I set additional compiler options for a project in Visual Studio 2008, they propagate to all files. If I then set additional options for a specific file, they are added to the project's command line and additional options. How can I compile an individual file without the project-wide options?

Comment: Err.. it works as expected for me. Generally speaking, though, compiler options need to match for the object files or linking will fail.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The behavior I described is indeed expected, but gives me no way of removing a switch specified at project level, as far as I can tell.

In my specific case, I need to compile all files with the /callcap switch, except for the file in which the hooks it inserts are implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that there's no way to negate /callcap for the one source file where you don't want it.  Ugly as it is, you could always place that one source file into a separate static library.